# What effect does fuel in ACT 1 and ACT 2 have on Cargo Carrying capacity on an A321 aircraft?

Tags: airbus-a320

Are there any limitations on how much cargo can be carried in H3,H4, and bulk on an A321 if there is fuel in ACT1 and ACT2?

What is the reference manual for this information?

Comment: Yes, there are limitations. Go to Weight and Balance Manual - Limitations - AFT Cargo Hold.